# Put through vs get through ( on the phone )

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I'd like to ask if I can :

> Can you get me through to the accounts department, please?

in order to mean

> Can you put me through to the accounts department, please?

---

> The lines were so busy but at last I managed to put through to one of
>   the consumer service workers.

in order to mean

> The lines were so busy but at last I managed to get through to one of
>   the consumer service workers.

Comment: The *normal* context-specific verb here is ***put***, but I think increasing numbers of younger (particularly, *American*) speakers tend to use ***get*** in all contexts where it's at least "credible" (which it definitely is here). From my personal perspective, ***get*** here carries a slightly stronger implication that making the through connection might be a little more difficult (for the speaker, and/or the person he's asking to do it for him).

Comment: But you would "**be** put through" in the third sentence. When you are calling, the operator is the one putting you through, so it's being done to you.

Comment: @Catija I know what you mean .Do you think the first two sentences are interchangeable though

Comment: The first one sounds more informal to me but, otherwise, yes... I wouldn't use either of them, though. I'd say "May I speak with someone in your accounts department, please".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way of asking for assistance over the phone is

> Could I speak to someone in accounts please.
>   I'd like to speak to someone in accounts please.
>   Accounts please.
>   I have a question about my account.

Being **put through** on a call is hold over from the days when there were central operators whom one had to speak to to make a connection, but the phrase can still be used today.

> The lines were so busy, but finally I was able to **get through** to customer service.
>   The lines were so busy, but finally I was able **to get** someone in customer service.

The caller is not the one **putting through** the connection, but is the one who **gets** the connection.

Answer (score -1):

In writing, there are times the rules *should* be discarded; your words *must not* sound awkward to the reader. Other than that, I use this theory when I cannot decide which one sounds better or is best: put is generally present and past tense for TO PLACE; get is usually present tense of TO GO. As you know, rules are broken all over the *place* (don't use 'put' or 'get' here!), but you'll *get* used to it (don't put 'put' here! ha, ha, couldn't resist cerebral "humor").

It seems to be that it's the 'to place' that sometimes becomes get/put.

To Place: I put the roast in the oven (vs. I got the roast in the oven)
To Go/unPlace: Get your feet off the table (vs Put your feet off the table)

Comment: Welcome to Ell, Teraisa. This question was asked in March, so it's quite old. You may want to look at the "Newest" tab on the questions list to find more recent questions. When you answer a question, please add references to your sources, and explain how it would be applied to **this question**.

Comment: I saw that it was not from NOW, but since I was looking it up and found this, I added for the next person who asks. And as for the sources, I didn't see that with the others so I am glad you let me know. Thank you so much, I look forward to working with everyone.